# Build Tensorflow iOS with env_time.cc:19:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found

Tags: c++, ios, makefile, tensorflow

I tried to build Tensorflow iOS on El Capitan and got into many errors. I have followed the changes in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/3382/files and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2936/files#r67559693 until I get to this error when running `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh`:

```
gcc --std=c++11 -I. -I/Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/ -I/Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen -I/Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/gemmlowp -I/Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/host_obj/ -I/Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf-host/include -I/usr/local/include -c tensorflow/core/platform/windows/env_time.cc -o /Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/host_obj/tensorflow/core/platform/windows/env_time.o
tensorflow/core/platform/windows/env_time.cc:19:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not
      found
#include <windows.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [/Users/myusername/tfv1/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/host_obj/tensorflow/core/platform/windows/env_time.o] Error 1
+ '[' 2 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo 'armv7 compilation failed.'
armv7 compilation failed.
+ exit 1
```

Does anyone know how to get pass that? I am assuming it's trying to build for Windows on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved the problem by deleting everything and started from scratch with these:

```
brew install bazel
brew install automake
brew install autoconf
brew uninstall libtool && brew install libtool
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
tensorflow/contrib/makefile/download_dependencies.sh
tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh
```